# .NET application UI crashing with unhandled exception

Tags: c#, crash, unhandled-exception

I have a .NET application that uses 'Scheduler' widget to display the appointments for chosen date filter.
This widget has a dropdown to choose a resource(Staff/Machine) for which it has display the appointments.
Issue: Upon choosing specific resource from this dropdown, i see a progress-bar to indicate the loading but it goes on-and-on and clicking anywhere in the application(host.DA.exe) UI causes it to crash with the standard Windows error reporting i.e. 'host.DA' has stopped working. 
I am not finding any clue as this is happening on Customer's machine and not reproducible at my end.

Here are the logs from Window event viewer:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          17.09.2014 09:02:06
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      KLINIKEN.INTERN
Description:
Application: host.da.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Stack:
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at Host.DA.App.Main()

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-09-17T07:02:06.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>14947</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>KLINIKEN.INTERN</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application: host.da.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Stack:
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at Host.DA.App.Main()
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

We don't have any symbols for this version of application shipped to our customer.
Therefore generating minidump was of no help to analyze.
To me, it appears to be unhandled exception but wondering what's that exception even .NET Framework is not catching?

Any clues/directions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the SEHException means you have unmanaged code in your project that causes an exception, might be your 'scheduler widget' or any [DllImport]... without more information on your code its hard to say what happens... you can get some clues if you google that exception https://www.google.com/search?q=SEHException

Comment: I got to know about SEHException thrown by unmanaged code. Ironically there is no such DllImport in our code other than just [assembly: ComVisible(false)] in AssemblyInfo.cs. Not sure what's happening here.

Comment: add more information, e.g. .net version, visual studio version, referenced assemblys, windows version, etc.